# Node.JS ChildProcess.on('exit') does not get hit when spawned process exits

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, exit, child-process

I have an executable written in C++ that runs calculations on a data file. Depending on the contents, these calculations can take from seconds to more than half an hour. I have an Electron application launching this executable and waiting for it to finish. My code is in the rendering process and it looks something like:

```js
this.exec = spawn(exeLocation, ['run', '-f', 'input file.dat']);

this.exec.stdout.on('data', doSomethingWithOutputData);
this.exec.stderr.on('data', doSomethingWithErrorData);

this.exec.on('exit', (code) => {
  console.log(`exit with code ${code}`);
  markExecTerminated();
});

this.exec.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`close with code ${code}`);
  markExecTerminated();
});
```

The problem I have is that the callbacks for `exit` and `close` get hit when the executable takes a few seconds or a few minutes, but when it takes over half an hour, the same callbacks never get called.

(Please note that originally I was handling only the `close` event. I added the `exit` event handler just to see if it would get called.)

I am completely stumped by this behavior. I would have expected consistent failure or success, but not something driven by how long it takes for the external exe to run.

I am looking for suggestions on why this is happening and/or how I can consistently get notified when the external exe finishes.

Comment: Do you have the opportunity to test if the same occurs on a different platform? I.e. on Windows or Linux or macOS? If you run the executable with inputs that cause this behavior from a shell, does the executable exit properly? Is it possible that the executable itself has a bug which causes the process to not exit properly? Do you get anything if you listen to `this.exec.on('error', err => {})`?

Comment: If you get the PID of the child process (`console.log(this.exec.pid)`), do you see the process in `ps aux | grep <pid>` even after the executable has supposedly exited? Do you still get the data you'd expect via stdout/stderr if `close`/`exit` never gets called?